# Confusion with two-mode bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation, coherent-states

Let us consider some abstract two-mode bosonic model with a conserved total number of quanta (i.e. eigenvalue $N$ of the operator $\hat{N} = a^\dagger a + b^\dagger b$ remains constant with corresponding subspace). Thus, the entire Hilbert space splits into a sum of invariant Hilbert sub-spaces for all $N = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. Thereunder, all of the states corresponding to the subspace with $N$ quanta have a form of a superposition of the blocks like $|n, N-n \rangle$, where $n = 0, 1, \dots, N$.

Thus, as far as I figured out, the coherent state reads
$$
|\alpha, \beta\rangle = e^{-(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)/2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n \beta^k}{\sqrt{n! k!} }|n, k\rangle \\  \rightarrow e^{-(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)/2}\sum_{m = 0}^N \frac{\alpha^m \beta^{N-m}}{\sqrt{m! (N-m)!}} |m, N-m\rangle,
$$
where I assumed $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = N$.

Let's consider the following state $|\alpha, 0 \rangle$, where $|\alpha|^2 = N$. I'm a bit confused, how will this state look like in the subspace with $N$ quanta?

Comment: Coherent states are a superposition of states with different numbers of quanta, so assumeing both coherent states and a fixed number of quanta is internally inconsistent. In particular $|\alpha|^2\ne N$.  What is probably true is that  $|\alpha|^2= \langle \alpha |\hat N|\alpha\rangle$ --- a rather different statement.

Comment: @mikestone But some state should correspond to the coherent state in this form of a basis.

Comment: you can’t express $\vert\alpha,0\rangle$ in the space of $N$ quanta alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You took an unfortunate left turn in your otherwise plausible reexpression of the first quadrant semi-infinite square lattice in terms of finite *N+1*- length diagonals thereof, stacked along the *n=k* line for all *N*s. As the comments warn you, one hardly ever constrains conjugate (Mellin) variables among themselves, anymore than one constrains *x* with *p* in Fourier transforms in QM.

Your coherent state is
$$
|\alpha, \beta\rangle = e^{-(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)/2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha^n \beta^k}{\sqrt{n! k!} }|n, k\rangle \\ =\sum_{N=0}^\infty  
e^{-(|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2)/2}\sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{\alpha^n \beta^{N-m}}{\sqrt{n! (N-n)!}} |n, N-n\rangle  \\ =e^{-|\alpha|^2  (1+|z|^2 )/2}  \sum_{N=0}^\infty \alpha^N
  \sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{   z^{N-n}}{\sqrt{n! (N-n)!}} |n, N-n\rangle ,
$$
where I  defined $\beta \equiv z \alpha$, so that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 =|\alpha|^2  (1+|z|^2 ) $.

---

*Possibly useful picture to summarize your rearrangement*: The lower right corner (SW) is the vacuum; the abscissa is *n*, going East, extending to infinity; and the ordinate *k*, increasing North, also extending to infinity.  Your inner sums are the finite diagonals SE to NW, of lengths 0, 1, 2, ... with 1, 2, 3 points each. The outer sum adds these diagonals from SW to NE, without limit.

[image: square lattice]

---

Your question of how does the one-mode coherent state $|\alpha, 0 \rangle$ sits in $|\alpha, z \alpha \rangle$ is  answerable by inspection of the lattice picture; as $z\to 0$, the only surviving term with vanishing exponent of the second (finite) sum is the topmost sum point at the beginning of the diagonal (*n=N*), $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{N! }} |N, 0 \rangle $,  restoring the standard one-mode coherent state: plug it in.

Comment: @Cosmaz Zachos Thank you for the answer!